# laravel- how can i get a user with all roles and all permissions with per role in orm in 5.1 with zizaco?

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-5.1, user-roles, role

I create all model and relations .
one user have many Roles and one Role have many Permissions.
i want a elequent that give a user with all roles and all permission for per role.

Comment: get all information about the logged in user information by `dd(Auth::user())` then you can choose any individual information by calling property like `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: I dont have Auth. I'm creating Api with jwt. and i want one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

now I create one function for this :

```
  public function getUserByMobileNumberWithRolesAndPermissions($mobile_number)
{
    $users = user::with('roles.permissions')->whereMobileNumber($mobile_number)->first();
    return is_null($users) ? null : $users->toArray();
}
```